Looking to assistance in recreating a trade analysis chart found on https://viz.ged-project.de/
Might anyone know how to reproduce this kind of visualization found on https://viz.ged-project.de/ using trade data? Would appreciate some directions. I tried recreating the chart in R and Python but my skills are still subpar. The visualizations I am getting are not anywhere close to that. To be frank, I used ChatGPT to create the code and iterate with it back and forth.
